# Как передавать значения переменных из Jenkins в Java проект

Tags: java, maven, test-automation, jenkins

Привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста,

есть проект, авто-тесты, которые, например создают некоторую сущность. Данные для этих сущностей беруться либо из `.properties` по ключам, либо из `.txt` документов опять же из ресурcов (директория).

Теперь задание, выложить это на дженкинс и настроить джобы с возможностью запуска с разными значениями.
Выложить то выложил, все собирается, но с теми данными, которые в файлах внутри проекта.

Нашел, что в Jenkins можно настраивать параметризацию, т.е. запускать с параметром.

Решил поступить так (пример возьмем, что нам при билде надо менять урл, это как пример, т.е. вместо урлы может быть абсолютно любое значение и их может быть несколько):

- на Jenkins создаю Job Item, указываю параметр `"This project is parameterized" = True`

Создаю переменную:

```
String Parameter
Name = generalUrl
Default Value = http://ru.stackoverflow.com
```

далее, указываю, что этот job item должен собираться с помощью `maven`, путь к `pom.xml` и все такое.
И в goal прописываю - `clean test`

Сохраняю.

- Иду в проект, в файле pom.xml указываю

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com</groupId>
<artifactId>erm-nav-qa-integration-test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <selenium.java.version>2.53.1</selenium.java.version>
    <testng.version>6.9.10</testng.version>
    <selenide.version>3.9.2</selenide.version>
    <junit.vesrion>4.12</junit.vesrion>
    <allure.version>1.4.23</allure.version>
    <maven.surefire.version>2.19.1</maven.surefire.version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.5</aspectj.version>
    <maven.compiler.version>3.5.1</maven.compiler.version>
    <jetty.version>9.3.11.v20160721</jetty.version>
    <allure.maven.version>2.5</allure.maven.version>
    <apache.poi.version>3.9</apache.poi.version>
    <suiteName>smoke_ui_tests.xml</suiteName>
    <generalUrl>http://ru.stackoverflow.com</generalUrl>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
        <version>${selenide.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.vesrion}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${apache.poi.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>

    <pluginManagement>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
                <configuration>

                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>${suiteName}</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>

                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>

                    <properties>
                        <testUrl>${generalUrl}</testUrl>
                    </properties>

                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--Needed only to show reports locally. Run jetty:run and
                open localhost:8080 to show the report-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </pluginManagement>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

</build>

<reporting>

    <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${allure.maven.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <properties>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-reports/</outputDirectory>
                    <allureResultsDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-results</allureResultsDirectory>
                </properties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/site</outputDirectory>

</reporting>
```

В файле `.properties` есть ключ с значнием `baseUrl=${generalUrl}`.
Вроде бы все сделал как находил по кусочкам где-то, запускаю свои тесты, получаю ошибку:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}
  (Session info: chrome=53.0.2785.89)
```

Включаю дебаггер и вижу, что на этапе чтения файла `.properties`, система берет просто `${generalUrl}`, т.е. просто как текст...

Подскажите, как можно из Jenkins передавать переменные, т.е. как настроить сам `pom.xml`, `.properties`, чтобы можно было выполнять параметризированный запуск.

Спасибо.

UPD: Добавил pom.xml

Comment: Что-то я не вижу у вас записи в файл `.properties`

Comment: @Aleksandr Согласен. Я чувствовал что, где-то что-то не так :). Вопрос - как и в какой момент выполнения билда сборки писать в файл `.properties` И что писать?...

Answer (score 6):

У вас по сути есть две задачи:

- пробросить значения параметров сборки из Jenkins в свойство maven-проекта (property).
- обработать `.properties`-файл(ы), заменяя заглушки `${generalUrl}` на значения свойств maven-а.

---

1. Maven интерпретирует аргументы JVM `-Dfoo=bar` в качестве свойств проекта.  Значения параметров сборки Jenkins доступны в виде макросов вида  `${MYPARAM}`.

   Чтобы передать параметр из Jenkins в maven, в соответствующем шаге сборки в поле <kbd>Goals and options</kbd> остается связать свойство maven с параметром Jenkins примерно так:

   ```
   <!-- language: none -->

   clean install -DgeneralUrl=${generalUrl}
   ```

   (замените `clean install` на то, что используетя в вашем случае)

---

2. Для подстановки свойств в ресурсы у maven есть готовое решение в составе Maven Resources Plugin - [фильтрация ресурсов](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html).

   Добавьте в `pom.xml` плагин актуальной версии:

   ```
   <!-- language: xml -->

   <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.1</version>
   </plugin>
   ```

   Просто в секции `<build>` вашего pom-файла включите фильтрацию для нужных ресурсов:

   ```
   <!-- language: xml -->

   <resource>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
       <filtering>true</filtering>
     </resource>
   <resource>
   ```

   Теперь при выполненнии maven-ом фазы `process-test-resources` будет выполняться задача `resources:testResources`, которая заменит выражение `${generalUrl}` в файле `src/main/resources/data.properties`  на свойство `generalUrl` из pom-файла, которое в свое очередь может пробрасываться из Jenkins.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Получается, что я по сути могу выполнить через консоль обычный запрос `mvn clean -DgeneralUrl=http://google.com test`, т.е. как бы сделать имитацию команды с Jenkins, так? И в этом случае, `mvn` передаст параметр `generalUrl` с значением `http://google.com`, в свою очередь плагин, вставленный в модуль `build`, выполнит проброску этого значения в `.properties` файл и метод, который считывает значение, в итоге получит `http://google.com`. Так?

Comment: Да, все именно так

Comment: Собственно Jenkins запускает Maven "обычным консольным запросом", а не волшебством )

Comment: Я добавил описание `pom.xml` файла и при запуске команды описанной выше из консоли, я получаю ошибку:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project erm-nav-qa-integration-test: Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test for parameter properties: Cannot assign configuration entry 'properties' with value 'http://google.com' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.util.Properties -> [Help 1]`

Comment: @AndreyYaremenko, проблема, очевидно, в строке `<properties>${generalUrl}</properties>`.

Comment: @Notate, исправил pom.xml сделал так, добавил еще один тег `<properties><testUrl>${generalUrl}</testUrl></properties>`

Но теперь ошибка следующая:

`org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: unhandled inspector error: {"code":-32603,"message":"Cannot navigate to invalid URL"}`

т.е. да, он теперь читает файл pom корректно, но значение из команды не пробрасывает в `.properties`, как я понял...

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо! Решил с помощью профилей
http://software-testing.ru/library/testing/general-testing/1984

И немного переписал загрузку из проперти файлов. По ссылке выше, все детально рассказывается и есть ссылка на архетип проекта, с примером пома с профилями.

Теперь тесты запускаются как локально из IDE, береться дефолтное значение из "дибаг.проперти", так и с помощью команды `mvn clean -DgeneralUrl=http://google.com test`, которое пробрасывает это значение переменной в проект. Дальше с настройкой в Jenkins, дело житейское :).

Comment: Разместите это как апдейт к вашему вопросу.